# 30"-35" Monitor for gaming and movies

Tags: monitors

I'm looking for a new PC monitor that will last for a long time. Right now I have some Samsung monitor, and I'm happy with it; however, it has <2k, and it's 7 years old, so I figured it's time for upgrade.

My budget is 2000zł(~470euro|~500$)

What monitor would be nice in this budget, 2k or more, for gaming and watching movies?

Comment: Can you narrow down your requirements please? As it stands this question is either too broad or too opinion based, both of which will yield many (potentially low quality) answers. This can be a great question if you edit it.

Comment: @Cfinley what should I change?

Comment: Your question has a handful of "should I do this, or this" type sub-questions in it. These types of questions are asking for an opinion, which is hard to answer (hence the close reason). If you choose one or the other for each requirement listed, this question can be reopened. (Also, you can have a 4K curved monitor.)

Comment: But not in this price range :)

Comment: @Cfinley Is it okay now? I previously wrote all of this to provide some research(as I'm used to getting bashed by other SE sites for not showing any research effort), but if that's the problem, I remove it. Is the quesiton now good enough?

Comment: As you complain that your current monitor has a resolution less than 2K, I would add a minimum resolution that you want. If you want to show research effort, you can show what you have found and what concerns you have about them, but this is not required.  Other than that, it looks good.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the [LG 34UM95C](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34UM95C-P-ultrawide-led-monitor). It is a great 34" WQHD 21:9 monitor that would be great for both movies and game. It is good for movies since it is a 21:9 ratio so the top black bars in movies are gone. Combined with the excellent color reproduction of the IPS display, it makes movies very enjoyable. The 5ms response time is also great for gaming for minimal lag. The UltraWide also makes the game more immersive.

Answer (score 2):

The **[HP ENVY 32](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-envy-32-inch-media-display-with-beats-audio)** is what I'd recommend for gaming and movies

[image]

This is a slight step up from 1080p which has a resolution of 2560 x 1440 (60 hertz) but without the strain of 4K on price and your computer. It has a fast 7ms response time which shouldn't cause any lag in games. It comes with a remote control which also makes it great for watching movies along with a bright 300 nits display. Reviews also praise this monitor for providing a great movie and gaming experience.